# Random number generator in java with long seed values

Tags: javascript, java, random

Super noob question (from a guy not understanding the bitwise stuff):

I use the pseudo random number generator below in JavaScript (on my server).

```
Math.seed = function(s) {
    var m_w  = s;
    var m_z  = 987654321;
    var mask = 0xffffffff;

    return function() {
      m_z = (36969 * (m_z & 65535) + (m_z >> 16)) & mask;
      m_w = (18000 * (m_w & 65535) + (m_w >> 16)) & mask;

      var result = ((m_z << 16) + m_w) & mask;
      result /= 4294967296;

      return result + 0.5;
    }
}

var myRandomFunction = Math.seed(1234);
var randomNumber = myRandomFunction();
```

Now I want to use it in Java (on my client). This works fine for int seed values (e.g. a seed of 1234 gives same numbers on JS and Java), but my seed value is long. How do I have to change the bitwise operators?

```
public class CodeGenerator {
    private int m_w;
    private int mask;
    private int m_z;

    public CodeGenerator(int seed) {
        m_w = seed;
        m_z = 987654321;
        mask = 0xffffffff;
    }

    public int nextCode() {
        m_z = (36969 * (m_z & 65535) + (m_z >> 16)) & mask;
        m_w = (18000 * (m_w & 65535) + (m_w >> 16)) & mask;
        int result = ((m_z << 16) + m_w) & mask;
        double result2 = result / 4294967296.0;
        return (int)Math.floor((result2 + 0.5) * 999999);
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity... Why aren't you using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html ?

Comment: Declare you variables and method with long.

Comment: @fhofmann this generates different numbers. i need them the same for the same seed.

Comment: @Niels The JS part is fix on the server. I have to use it on the client to get the same numbers.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you need to mask the seed to unsigned int then it produces the same numbers as the JS version.

New constructor:

```
public CodeGenerator(long seed) {
    mask = 0xffffffff;
    m_w = (int) (seed & mask);
    m_z = 987654321;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried declare only the seed and first result as long?

```
public class CodeGenerator {
    private long m_w;
    private int mask;
    private int m_z;

    public static void main(String... a){
        System.out.println(new CodeGenerator(1234).nextCode()); //result = 237455
        System.out.println(new CodeGenerator(1234567891234L).nextCode()); //result = 246468
    }

    public CodeGenerator(long seed) {
        m_w = seed;
        m_z = 987654321;
        mask = 0xffffffff;
    }

    public int nextCode() {
        m_z = (36969 * (m_z & 65535) + (m_z >> 16)) & mask;
        m_w = (18000 * (m_w & 65535) + (m_w >> 16)) & mask;
        long result = ((m_z << 16) + m_w) & mask;
        double result2 = result / 4294967296.0;
        return (int)Math.floor((result2 + 0.5) * 999999);
    }
}
```